# Ansible replacing the last bit of an ip using a playbook

Tags: ansible

I wrote a playbook with the purpose of changing the last bit of the default gateway ip of all the hosts in my inventory.ini

So far I am able to change the last bit through this command :

```sh
cat /etc/network/interfaces | grep -i default | awk -F'.' -vOFS='.' '{$NF=6}1;' > /etc/network/interfaces
```

But the problem is that I still cannot figure out how to replace only the last line of the interfaces file without overwriting the whole content of the file.

Here's how my playbook look like :

```yaml
---
- name: test connectivity
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: ping
      ping:
    - name: change default gateway address
      command: cat /etc/network/interfaces | grep -i default | awk -F'.' -vOFS='.' '{$NF=6}1;' > /etc/network/interfaces 
    - name: restart networking service
      command: systemctl restart networking
    - name: check ip configuration
      command: netstat -rn
...
```

All hint and tips are more than welcome.

Comment: `cat /etc/network/interfaces .... > /etc/network/interfaces` Use a temporary file. You are lucky the file is not empty.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it ? could you please explain what you mean by i'm lucky the file is not empty

Comment: https://edwards.sdsu.edu/research/reading-and-writing-to-the-same-file/ looks fine. `command: systemctl restart networking` Use `service: name=networking state=restarted`.

Comment: and to add up to @KamilCuk, Ansible have a `replace` module just for that. If you are going to stuff a playbook with shell command, maybe it would be best to stick to pure ssh, to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after many tries and after taking the advice of using ansible modules in account I came out with this gem of a playbook that helped me reach my goal :

```yaml
---
- name: test connectivity
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: ping
      ping:
    - name: change default gateway address
      replace:
        path: /etc/network/interfaces
        regexp: '(up route add default gw [\d]*\.[\d]*.[\d]*)\.[\d]*$'
        replace: '\1.6'
        backup: yes
      when: (ansible_facts['distribution'] == "Debian")
    - name: restart networking serviice
      service:
        name: networking
        state: restarted
      when: (ansible_facts['distribution'] == "Debian")
    - name: change default gateway address on Redhat
      replace:
        path: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
        regexp: '(GATEWAY=[\d]*\.[\d]*.[\d]*)\.[\d]*$'
        replace: '\1.6'
        backup: yes
      when: (ansible_facts['distribution'] == "RedHat")
    - name: restart networking service for Redhat
      service:
        name: network
        state: restarted
      when: (ansible_facts['distribution'] == "RedHat")
...
```

It is working just as expected and of course it can be enhanced for other context. Thank you all for your advices and help

Answer (score 3):

Have your playbook of Ansible in this way. This is completely based on your shown samples. I couldn't test it since I don't have Ansible with me, though command should work.

```yaml
---
- name: test connectivity
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: ping
      ping:
    - name: change default gateway address
      command: tac /etc/network/interfaces | awk -F'.' -v IGNORECASE="1" -v OFS="." '/default/{if(FNR==1){$NF=6};print}' | tac  > temp && mv temp /etc/network/interfaces 
    - name: restart networking service
      command: systemctl restart networking
    - name: check ip configuration
      command: netstat -rn
# ...
```

***Fixes done in OP's attempt:***

- I have also taken care of your overwriting issue, where you are overwriting your same Input_file without inplace option OR without using a temp output file. Because if try to update an Input_file while `awk` program is reading it, it gets empty because we are not using inplace option to perform same(which creates temp file in backend and saves output into it and then renames that file to Input_file).
- Removed `grep` command since `awk` can take care of by itself, so attached the logic of grep into `awk` code itself.

Comment: @Jinja_dude, `tac` is not a typo, `tac` is a command which prints file from bottom line(as a first line, just opposite of `cat`), so this is intentional in code(so that `awk` could get last line as first line and once awk is done with its processing again using tac will print the actual contents sequence then), cheers.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to read and respond, and yes you're right about tac I just checked out. and i tried your solution and I have this error now I am trying to understand the reason behind it

Comment: fatal: [test-vipgw-debian]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["tac", "/etc/network/interfaces", "|", "awk", "-F.", "-v", "IGNORECASE=1", "-v", "OFS=.", "/default/{if(FNR==1){$NF=254};print}", "|", "tac", ">", "temp", "&&", "mv", "temp", "/etc/network/interfaces"], "delta": "0:00:00.011036", "end": "2021-02-03 20:46:52.687298", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2021-02-03 20:46:52.676262", "stderr": "tac: invalid option -- 'F'\nTry 'tac --help' for more information.", "stderr_lines": ["tac: invalid option -- 'F'", "Try 'tac --help' for more information."]: []}
```

Comment: @Jinja_dude, I am not sure on Ansible side but looks like(by seeing your error) -F is getting passed to it which shouldn't be the case try to run this as a single comment itself once? Again I am sorry I am not sure on Ansible side but command should work fine if you want to test it give it a try in a test file

Comment: I'd suspect a YAML syntax issue, where the whole string should be quoted (single or double) but then you'll have to escape the relevant quotes of the shell command itself

Answer (score 2):

Q: **"*Ansible replacing the last line of file*"**

A: Given a file

```sh
shell> cat test.txt
l1
l2
l3
```

the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    replace_line: last line replacement
  tasks:
    - command: cat test.txt
      register: result
    - copy:
        dest: test.txt
        content: |
          {% for line in result.stdout_lines[:-1] %}
          {{ line }}
          {% endfor %}
          {{ replace_line }}
```

gives

```sh
shell> cat test.txt
l1
l2
last line replacement
```

The playbook is idempotent.

Comment: thank you for your answer, matter of fact this could help I'll try to adapt it with my playbook.